# Espresso hangs the UI and the System kills the application

Tags: android-espresso

I have several test classes for Espresso tests. One of the test class fails in the middle when I try to run all the test together. When I run the failing class separately, then it runs smoothly. The log from Espresso is the following:

***Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'***

The debug log shows the following message:

```
D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change: RESUMED
W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
W/google-breakpad: 3.13
W/google-breakpad: 110
W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9119
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
```

Which says the the process was killed by the system, because the UI was hanged.

So what could be the possible reason for this?

EDIT:

After checking the same tests on 2 Nexus 5 devices, turns out that the crash happens on the device which has Android version **6.0. On 7.0** it works fine.